# Get Access Token from Spotify API using OpenFeign (Spring Boot Java)

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spotify, openfeign

I am building a project that involves authentication with the Spotify API. I managed to get to the first part and receive the access code from the Spotify API. My problem is when I try to make a POST request to https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token . I first make a JSON object with parameters such as the code, the access type and the redirect uri. I also try to send a header with the Authorization information. This is what it looks like

```
@FeignClient(name = "authentication", url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token")
public interface AuthenticationProxy {

    @PostMapping(value = "", produces = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public EntityResponse<SpotifyTokens> getAccessToken
            (@RequestBody JSONObject body,
             @RequestHeader(name = "Authorization") String authorization);
}
```

However when I launch the application and get to this endpoint this is the response I get :
feign.FeignException$UnsupportedMediaType: [415 Unsupported Media Type] during [POST] to [https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token] [AuthenticationProxy#getAccessToken(JSONObject,String)]

Does anyone knows how to fix this?
Thank you.

I first tried to send directly my own objects, then I used the JSON dependency to create JSON objects. Then instead of trying to send a body using @RequestBody I tried to send each parameters by themselves using @RequestParam. I have no idea how to fix this.